# Added data disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery

**jQuery Core 3.1.0**

**Chrome, Firefox**

Below is a model of jquery.ajax() success behaviour.

Shortly: I managed to fetch data via AJAX. In this model example the data is represented by "Just something" placeholder. Now I want to add the data to the document.

```
<script>
var add_date = $("#add_date");

function add_date_ajax(){
    $('.frame_date').append("Just something");
    debugger; // 1
}
debugger; // 2
add_date.click(add_date_ajax);
</script>
```

**A problem: the data appear and then disappear in half a second.**

I placed breakpoints.

When the page is loading, it stops at breakpoint 2. That is correct.

When I click #add_date element, the script stops at breakpoint 1. That is also correct.

But when I click "resume script execution", the script again goes to breakpoint 2. This seem strange to me. As if the page is reloaded. Maybe that is why the added text disappears.

Could you help me cope with the problem?

**Added later:**

https://jsfiddle.net/mv1yu3zw/1/

Comment: Fiddle added. Please, have a look at the bottom of the question.

Comment: you just miss # in your href. if you did not use # in href, the a will direct to other link or reflash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It disappears because you are reloading the page. The html

```
<a href="" id="add_date">Add date</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="#" id="add_date">Add date</a>
```

Comment: Using # in `href` attribute is considered a bad design. What it actually will do is jumping to the top of the page if the default action is not prevented, which can lead to annoying UI bugs. Much better would be to use a `<button>` instead.

Comment: @KamilLatosinski definitely agree there, was just sticking within the realm of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

To bind all your events, you should use the `ready` on `document`.

To avoid the reloading of your page (because of the `href` of the `a` tag), you have to call `preventDefault` or use a `button`.

You should write your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_date").on("click", add_date_ajax);
});

function add_date_ajax(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.frame_date').append("Just something");
}
```